# How do I make my Discord js Bot check if someone is typing in the bots dms?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I want my bot to check if someone's typing in the bots dms. How do I do that?

```
Client.on("typingStart", async function(channel, user){
        console.log(channel)
        console.log(user)
        if(channel.type == "dm"){
            console.log("one")
            while(user.typing){
                console.log("two")
                Sleep(2000)
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're encountering the same issue as the one stated [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/4771). From there it states that:

> The event can only emit on client if the channel is cached, discord.js otherwise drops the event (does not emit it). In this case this means you did not have a DM during the bots session from either side (you -> bot/ bot- > you), else the channel would be created/cached.

You can overcome this by enabling `partials` in your `client`, but it states in the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.5.3/typedef/ClientOptions) that: *partials require you to put checks in place when handling data*.

With that being said, you can simply replace your `Client` declaration with this so that the event will be emitted for a DM:

```js
const Client = new Discord.Client({
    partials: ["CHANNEL", "USER"]
});
```